# Gatling Pressure Testing of GAE Go App Results in 'java.net.SocketException: Too many open files'

Tags: google-app-engine, go, socketexception, gatling

I'm pressuring testing my Go app deployed on GAE (10000 users ramped over 60 seconds, making 30 requests each) with Gatling (http://gatling.io/#/) and am seeing the following two errors:

```
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files                    6132 (82.98%)
> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files in system          1248 (16.89%)

---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
> t < 800 ms                                        301457 ( 97%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                 908 (  0%)
> t > 1200 ms                                          245 (  0%)
> failed                                              7390 (  2%)
================================================================================
```

From what I understand this has to do with the VM configuration and could potentially be fixed by upping the limits on open files `ulimit -n <value>`.

What I don't understand is -- how do I manage the GAE VM settings? There are some config options in dev console... but is there a way I can access the underlying VM itself? Or do I have to forego GAE for compute engine and setting up my own managed VMs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the limit isn't being hit on the machine you're running the load-test from?

Comment: That was it, thanks @Greg. Solved with 'echo limit maxfiles 100000 100000|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf' and restarting (up'ing my ulimit -n). If you want to write that as an answer happy to give you credit.